# How to enable verbosity on "alembic upgrade head"?

Tags: python, alembic

In one of the python projects I'm working on we are using alembic to handle the DB migration scripts.
Lately he had an incident when container ,in which alembic upgrade head is running, got stucked ( by some locks on the DB set the the runtime app) and eventually timed out without giving any details of what was going on. Finally we managed to get access to prod DB (which under normal circumstances we are not allow to access. this is something imposed by our cloudops team, for security reasons). 
So in order to eas our debugging process, i would like to enable verbose mode when calling "alembic upgrade head", this without having to add a tone of logs on top of the migration scripts.

I found that --verbose flag is accepted for some alembic operations, but for some reasons "alembic upgrade head" doesn't allow it.

*usage: alembic [-h] [-c CONFIG] [-n NAME] [-x X] [--raiseerr]
               {branches,current,downgrade,edit,heads,history,init,list_templates,merge,revision,show,stamp,upgrade}
               ...
alembic: error: unrecognized arguments: --verbose*

This is the call generating the error above: *alembic upgrade head --verbose*

Any idea on how I can enable verbosity on upgrade?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

in `alembic.ini` set the field **[logger_sqlalchemy]** level to **INFO** or **DEBUG**

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like verbose is not working in this case. More details here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy-alembic/kpCYbkfHLeA